# Prevent Adobe Reader from switching to "Fit Page" zoom when bookmark is clicked

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

If I open a PDF document in Adobe Reader, it usually opens with **Fit Width** page zoom by default.

But if I click on a bookmark, the zoom changes to **Fit Page**.

How do I stop this from happening and have Adobe Reader maintain the default zoom?

Comment: The seemingly insane decisions Adobe ends up with when designing and implementing their software, has long gotten the best of me. The board of directors there and/or management must be extraterrestrials from Zeta Reticulae or somewhere there.

Comment: see my answer further below using foxit.

Answer (score 6):

**In Foxit Reader**, there is a Preference Setting... (File -> Preferences )..

Adobe Reader may have similar functionality.. OR use Foxit Reader... which is a great pdf viewer.

Choose: Page Display, in the Left Pane.

Then "Check" Forbid the Change of the current Zoom factor.

This will preserve the Current Zoom when moving around with BookMarks.

Hope this helps..

**Please Note Foxit PDF Reader is FREE!!! and you can download from this link:** https://www.foxit.com/pdf-reader/

*At time of installation, you can uncheck any recommendation the software is trying to add (e.g. browser plugins, antivirus, etc.)*

[image]

Comment: I'm not going to pay this company $175/year, every year (which is what they're requesting!!!), for the rest of my life, for permission to use some piece of software I'll probably only use once, and when I do use it it won't work as advertised, no. Request denied. And I'm offended that you would put such a request on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @RobbieHatley what are you talking about??. Foxit is free. Adobe reader is free. No one is asking you to pay anything anywhere. May be you meant to reply some other posting.

Comment: Re "Foxit is free": The product being advertised here, when I went to their web site, was NOT "free", else I would not have said otherwise. Simply contradicting truths you don't like in the Stack Exchange good-old-boys cesspool and expecting them to "go away" may "work" for you HERE, but if you try that in real life, the results will be bad.

Comment: @RobbieHatley Foxit PDF Reader is Free. Just the reader. here is the url: https://www.foxit.com/pdf-reader/       and also at time of installation of the "FREE READER".. you can also uncheck any additional recommendation it asks you to add.. e.g. browser plugins, etc. go the above link, download (i repeat it is FREE download).. and install and enjoy the "pdf reader" for your use.

Comment: I don't think "use another software" is a proper answer to a question "how to do A in software X?"

Comment: i agree. but unfortunately, in adobe reader.. as per the answer below.. it is not possible. So, let the OP decide what is best for him/her... either convince adobe to have similar feature by looking at Foxit preference settings (now that it is known).. or write some sort of macro (many such tools exist.. e.g. AutoHotKey or any other).. answering it is not possible in adobe reader.. limits the choices that are available.. now it opens many doors.   OR wait for some future reader to convince otherwise, that it is possible in Adobe Reader with Setting: X... or any other suggestions.

Comment: @GenePavlovsky I have to agree with ihightower. I wanted to do this on Adobe Reader, but it doesn't offer the functionality. In a scenario like this, offering an alternative is a good answer. One can't always find a solution, but sometimes a workaround will help.

Comment: @RobbieHatley FoxIt Reader is freeware. They do have a pro version and a suite that people can buy. However, saying that their reader is not free because they offer a paid pro version is the same as saying Adobe Reader isn't free because you have to pay to use Adobe Acrobat (the pro version of the reader) is a nonsensical argument.

Comment: @ihightower Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: @AristidesColon-Castillo I myself use SumatraPDF for most of my PDF viewing. But some stuff (usually various forms to fill out) only work properly in Adobe Reader (well, I haven't tried Foxit PDF Reader). I'm just guessing Reader has some setting somewhere that would answer the question without changing the software.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry in advance if I'm breaking any rules here. I don't have enough reputation points to give this answer an up arrow, but I thought people deserved to know that this worked for me--like a charm!

From above:

> "The way to do it is, edit the afflicted PDF files themselves. Open each malfunctioning file in a hex editor (I recommend "HxD" because it's free; search for it), and do this replace globally: `/Fit` -> `/XYZ`, then save the file with a new name.

Voilà, problem will be fixed; the document will then retain whatever zoom setting you set in Adobe Reader settings, no matter how many bookmarks you click."

In what rational universe must I have "reputation points" to share my success with others and help them to resolve this question that has clearly daunted so many?

Comment: This worked as a charm, but I needed to do it in two steps: first replace /Fit by /XYZ. Then, replace /XYZH by /XYZ. BTW, I used Notepad ++...

Comment: For anyone editing bookmark destinations this way, the destination syntax & how to control zoom are given [in section 12.3.2.2, “Explicit Destinations”, of the PDF standard](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=374). That link goes to the standard for PDF 1.7 that Adobe hosts; you can also download the latest standard from [pdfa.org/resource/iso-32000-pdf](https://pdfa.org/resource/iso-32000-pdf/).
 Directly changing `/Fit` → `/XYZ` after decompressing the PDF with `mutool clean -gggglsdfi ORIGINAL.pdf EXPANDED.pdf` worked well for me.

Comment: follow up: just changing `/Fit` → `/XYZ` breaks bookmarks on some PDF viewers (like firefox 121’s built in pdfjs), b/c `/XYZ` is supposed to take 3 arguments: [`/XYZ left top zoom`](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=374) & `/Fit` takes none. you can avoid this by changing `/Fit` → `/XYZ null null null` (_null_ means "keep the current values" here) but since this lengthens each bookmark, you won't be able to use a hex editor (I used emacs) & should repair the PDF afterwards w/ something like `mutool clean -gggglsdfiz FIT.pdf XYZ.pdf`

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot change this behavior by fiddling with *Edit/Preference/Page Display/Zoom* settings, then you may well have the case of the bookmark being tied to an *"Action"*.

Unfortunately, you cannot change that with Acrobat Reader -- you'd need access to Adobe Acrobat or to Acrobat Professional (or maybe some other tool with similar capabilities in this respect).

Here are some screenshots which illustrate what I mean:

[image: Right-click the bookmark and move mouse pointer to "Properties..." on lower end of context menu...]

Right-click the bookmark and move mouse pointer to "Properties..." on lower end of context menu...

[image: ...and the dialog to edit/add/delete "Actions" appears]

...and the dialog to edit/add/delete "Actions" appears

Comment: But how could we change all the bookmarks at once?

Comment: @cqcn: Mark ***ALL*** bookmarks at once, then right-click...

Comment: But that may change the `page target` of all the bookmarks into one. I'm not sure if this is also true for you?

Comment: I may not be clear. That IS the result that I get. But I'm not sure if this my problem or the bug of Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: @cqcn1991: Me neither. You'll have to change your bookmarks one by one then.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, this can happen even if the Bookmark link has no "Zoom level" action. In my case (Acrobat Pro 9.5.5), it happened because each Bookmark links to a Destination, and the Destinations themselves apparently have the Fit Width zoom level.

I verified this by double clicking on a Destination (from the Destinations navigation panel) to open it, changing my zoom settings to Fit Page, then right clicking on the Destination and selecting Set Destination. Afterward, that particular bookmark resulted in Fit Page while the others still resulted in Fit Width.

I solved this with a nifty plugin PubHelper, which is no longer maintained but worked for me: https://web.archive.org/web/20150814072039/http://pubhelper.blogspot.com/ . I selected all bookmarks, then PubHelper->Bookmarks->To Inherit Zoom.

BTW, I don't think this issue is specific to "Fit Width" being chosen. I think it's a general issue where bookmarks can override the user's current zoom settings.

Comment: That blog does not exist. So if the thing which was there (whatever it was) has been moved elsewhere, I suggest editing your answer to indicate the current ACTUAL location of the thing in-question.

Comment: Thanks to whoever changed the link to the Archive.org link.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the Hand tool from following an article path, go to the the Edit menu and choose Preferences. In the General category, uncheck "Make Hand tool read articles".

Comment: That's not an answer to the question that was asked, and does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This still seems to be a problem in 2020 and  I didn't want to install java for the above solution.

So for the next person that comes across this, you can rid the bookmark of its saved zoom by setting each of the bookmarks zoom factor to 0, or some other float  to enforce some other zoom factor.

I made a python script which seems to do the job on the few pdf's that I've tested with. It requires pikepdf from pip.

```
import pikepdf,sys,os,argparse

class data:
    _names = None
    
def update_dest(zoom_factor,current):
    dest = pikepdf.Array()
    dest.append(current[0])
    dest.append(pikepdf.Name("/XYZ"))
    dest.append(0)
    dest.append(0)
    dest.append(zoom_factor)
    dest_type = current[1]
    
    if dest_type == "/XYZ":
        dest[2] = current[2]
        dest[3] = current[3]
    elif dest_type in ("/FitH","FitBH"):            
        dest[3] = current[2]          
    elif dest_type in ("/FitV","FitBV"):            
        dest[2] = current[2]          
    elif dest_type == "/FitR":
        dest[2] = current[2]
        dest[3] = current[4]
    #("/Fit","/FitB"):
    
    return dest    
       
def collect_all_names(root):
    if not hasattr(root,"Names"):
        return {}
        
    names = {}

    def _apply_collect_all_names(parent):
        if hasattr(parent,"Kids"):
            for item in parent.Kids:
                _apply_collect_all_names(item)   
        elif hasattr(parent,"Names"):
            for index in range(0,len(parent.Names),2):
                names[parent.Names[index]] = (index+1,parent.Names)
            
    _apply_collect_all_names(root.Names.Dests)
  
    return names
    
def get_names(root):
    if not data._names:
        data._names = collect_all_names(root)
    return data._names

def set_zoom_factor(root,depth,outline_item,zoom_factor,only_bookmarks): 

    skipped = False
    if outline_item.action:
        outline_item.action.D = update_dest(zoom_factor,outline_item.action.D)
    elif outline_item.destination != None:
        if only_bookmarks:
            names = get_names(root)
            if outline_item.destination in names:
                index = names[outline_item.destination][0]
                array = names[outline_item.destination][1]
                array[index] = update_dest(zoom_factor,array[index])
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("Name %s Not Found" % outline_item.destination)
    else:
        skipped = True

    print(("skipped" if skipped else "updated") + " >> %s %s" % (" "*depth,outline_item.title))
    
    
def set_all_bookmark_zooms(in_file,out_file=None,zoom_factor=None,only_bookmarks=False):

    def _apply_set_all_bookmark_zoom(names,depth,children):
        for child in children:

            set_zoom_factor(names,depth,child,zoom_factor,only_bookmarks)
            _apply_set_all_bookmark_zoom(names,depth+1,child.children)
    
    pdf = pikepdf.open(in_file)

    if not only_bookmarks:
        names = get_names(pdf.root)
        for key,values in names.items():
            index,array = values
            array[index] = update_dest(zoom_factor,array[index])
            
    with pdf.open_outline() as outline:
        _apply_set_all_bookmark_zoom(pdf.root,0,outline.root)
        
    save_name = out_file if out_file else in_file.split(".")[0] + "-zoomed.pdf"
    print("saving %s ..." % save_name) 
    pdf.save(save_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Remove PDF bookmark zooms')
    parser.add_argument('-z','--zoom', type=float,default=None,
                        help='set the zoom factor of the bookmarks/links. 0 will inherit the current zoom (default:0)')
    parser.add_argument('-ob','--only_bookmarks',default=False,action="store_true",
                        help='only process bookmark links, other clickables in the document are left untouched (default:False)')
     
    parser.add_argument('file_name',help='PDF filename to process')     
    parser.add_argument('-o','--out_file',default=None,help='Output filename')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    set_all_bookmark_zooms(args.file_name,args.out_file,args.zoom,args.only_bookmarks)
```

[repo](https://github.com/rmawatson/pdf_bookmark_zoom_remover)

Comment: Well, after a lot of struggle (and installing dozens of dependencies, including Wheel, Qpdf, Pillow, PikePdf, libxml2, libxslt, etc, etc, etc, I finally got that to install and run. But it doesn't work. It saves a version of the original file with all the SAME bookmark zoom bugs as the original. So I think your script needs work.

Comment: works for me... I've used it on 100's pdfs.. https://github.com/rmawatson/pdf_bookmark_zoom_remover - attach the pdf on githib and I'll try it.

Comment: No, I'll just use my OWN method -- the one in the Answer I gave -- as that one is FULLY FUNCTIONAL, and is EASY, and doesn't require downloading and installing dozens of Python dependencies and troubleshooting other people's broken Python code for them. It just required downloading and installing any of the many available free hex editors, and changing all "/Fit" to "/XYZ" in the afflicted PDF files.

Answer (score 1):

Re "[How can I ] Prevent Adobe Reader from switching to “Fit Page” zoom when bookmark is clicked[?]": There *is* a way to do that, yes, but *not* from within Adobe reader settings. (To the best of my knowledge, Adobe Reader has never had that functionality and never will.) The way to do it is, edit the afflicted PDF files themselves. Open each malfunctioning file  in a hex editor (I recommend "HxD" because it's free; google for it), and do this replace globally: "/Fit" -> "/XYZ", then save the file with a new name. Voila, problem will be fixed; the document will then retain whatever zoom setting you set in Adobe Reader settings, no matter how many bookmarks you click.

Comment: This is only a solution to replace "Fit page" with "Inherit zoom", OP asked for "Fit width".

Comment: "beatngu13" : The OP did not ask for ANY specific alterations to PDF files, but rather, how to solve the "bookmarks alter zoom" problem by changing settings in Adobe Reader (or other PDF reader software). And the answer is, "You can't do that.". However, while that answer would be technically true, it's also disingenuous, as the problem CAN be solved. If one sets program to "fit with", then any PDF files edited as I describe will remain "fit width" regardless of bookmark clicks. That solves the stated problem, though in a different way from what was asked.

Comment: if anyone really wants to set a PDF’s bookmarks to open in "Fit width", they can globally replace `/Fit` with `/FitH` as above. there are a few other ways bookmarks can be opened (such as "Fit height"), which are given [in section 12.3.2.2, “Explicit Destinations”, of the PDF standard](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=374). that link goes to the standard for PDF 1.7 that Adobe hosts; you can also download the latest standard from [pdfa.org/resource/iso-32000-pdf](https://pdfa.org/resource/iso-32000-pdf/)

Comment: note that just changing `/Fit` → `/XYZ` breaks bookmarks on some PDF viewers (like firefox 121’s built in pdfjs), b/c `/XYZ` is supposed to take 3 arguments: [`/XYZ left top zoom`](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=374) & `/Fit` takes none. you can avoid this by changing `/Fit` → `/XYZ null null null` (_null_ means "keep the current values" here) but since this lengthens each bookmark, you won't be able to use a hex editor (I used emacs) & should repair the PDF afterwards w/ something like `mutool clean -gggglsdfiz FIT.pdf XYZ.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

#### Single PDF / Paid

Since the August 2020 release of Acrobat ([release notes](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/whats-new/2020-august.html#Setthedefaultzoomlevelforbookmarks)):

> Acrobat now provides an option in the bookmark properties to retain the destination page number when you adjust the zoom level of multiple bookmarks.

[image: Adobe Acrobat screenshot]

#### Single or Multiple PDFs / Free

I have created an open-source (Java-based) app that allows you to apply

- Actual size
- Fit page
- Fit visible
- Fit width
- Inherit zoom

to all bookmarks within a PDF document or recursively to entire directories of PDFs without selecting each item manually:

https://github.com/beatngu13/pdf-zoom-wizard/

[image: PDF Zoom Wizard screenshot]

Comment: Ok, I downloaded that, but it does nothing. Is there a version of this somewhere that actually DOES something?

Comment: @RobbieHatley if it doesn’t work for YOU, open an [issue](https://github.com/beatngu13/pdf-zoom-wizard/issues).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Adobe Acrobat Reader 2021**

Run the following sed command on the pdf file (i.e. you need to do this for each pdf file that you want this change, in the free Acrobat Reader there is no setting to fix this). The command replaces instances in the bookmark code from `/Fit` to `/XYZ`. On Windows you can run it on Cygwin (in the Cygwin setup install the `sed` package)

```
sed -b 's#/Fit#/XYZ#g' original.pdf > modified.pdf
```

Comment: I ran this command on MacOS, but got an error message saying "unterminated substitute pattern".